# shell, assigning value to variable from subscript

Tags: shell, zsh

(using zsh with the following)

```
# i=for loop ((i;i<l,i++))
typeset -A _opts
AILABLE_ARG_OPTS=('v|verbose' 0 'd|destination' 1)
currentOpt=("${(@s/=/)${@[$i]##*-}}")

for k v in ${(kv)AVAILABLE_ARG_OPTS}; do
  if (( $v != 0 )); then
    _opts[${k#*|}]=$([[ -v currentOpt[2] ]] &&  #<---------- subscript
      echo "${currentOpt[2]}" ||
      echo "${@[$((++i))]}"   # <---------------------------- HERE ?
    )
  fi
done
```

At 'HERE', $i using correct value but doesn't set increment for the loop.
- Did I miss something with the substitution ?
- Does the variable became readonly inner sub execution ?

---

edit add same style question..

```
_opts[${k#*|}]=${currentOpt[2]:-"${@[$((++i))]}"}
```

is it "normal" that the second statement is evaluate in all case ?
`$currentOpt[2]``setted or not

---

edit: (as comment answer)

```
_opts[${k#*|}]=$(
  [[ -v currentOpt[2] ]] &&  #<---------- subscript 
    echo "${currentOpt[2]}" ||
    echo "${@[$((++i))]}"   # <--------------------- $i is not incremented
)
```

"~~equivalent~~" to (exept that increment..)

```
if [[ -v currentOpt[2] ]]; then
  _opts[${k#*|}]="${currentOpt[2]}"
else
  _opts[${k#*|}]="${@[$((++i))]}" # <--------  $i is incremented
fi
```

that the point I don't understand, in both case the right value is setted to `_opts[$k]`.
But in the first exemple, `$((++i))` don't assign it's value to`$i`
.. and i would know why

thanks for help

Comment: You have a `||` on the preceding line, which means unless there is an error with the `echo` command, the "HERE" line never executes.

Comment: thanks, but that ok with that, assume we talk of an case where $currentOpt[2] is not setted, hilight for code is wrong at the line above the first echo, regex parse as an comment but i assign =$(.  I added more explain

Comment: You're incrementing `i` in a subshell created by the command substitution. `i` in the current shell isn't affected.

Comment: so parent shell variable are readonly ? does have a way to "reference" them ?

Comment: I guess that's one way of looking at it. More precisely, the child gets its own variable, initialized to the value of the parent's variable.

Comment: oh ok, thanks for answer. just have to use the second exemple, or make them env variable.....